# Jenkins Github plugin: how to make job to be triggered only by pushes to master branch?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am configuring Jenkins job which does a release of my app's build configured for our staging environment.

I enabled setting: `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub` which automatically added corresponding Github hook to my project's settings on Github and the hooks started to be triggered.

However I didn't find a way how to make this job to be triggered by **only the pushes to a master branch** not to any other branch.

My current observation is that `Github Plugin` doesn't allow this sort of configuration, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build triggers section **Build when a change is pushed to GitHub** are complemented by the desired branch information in the **Branches to build** area in the Source Code Management section.

[image]

This job will be triggered if jenkins receive PUSH GitHub hook from repo defined in specified branch.

Comment: Rogério Peixoto, thanks for the answer. I knew that before however I didn't realize that because of extensive debugging I was doing, my pushes to non-master branches **seemed** to trigger my job just because of I used to abort manually latest builds of master branch before (so Jenkins was considering master branch as one that had changes: "Changes found" in GitHub Hook Log). Your answer helped me to realize my mistake.